# Restricting Java generic parameter type to a list of final classes

Tags: java, generics, final, generic-list

`T` is unrestricted in the following declaration.

```
abstract public class Defaults<T>
```

However, my `Defaults` class deals with only `String`, `Integer`, `Double`. Therefore, I would like to restrict `T` to `String`, `Integer`, `Double`.

Obviously, the following is not allowed as they are finals:

```
abstract public class Defaults<T extends String&Integer&Double>
```

How then can I do it?

Comment: `class Container<T extends String>` is allowed with an warning. With that I get bound mismatch error for `Container<Object>`. So, I think "Obviously, the following is not allowed as they are finals:" is not correct.

Comment: Precision in quoting me: <T extends String&Integer&Double> vs <T extends String>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot.  The closest thing you can do is give `Defaults` a private constructor

```
private Defaults() {}
```

...and provide factory methods only for the allowed classes:

```
public static Defaults<String> stringDefaults() { return new Defaults<>(); }
public static Defaults<Integer> integerDefaults() { return new Defaults<>(); }
public static Defaults<Double> doubleDefaults() { return new Defaults<>(); }
```